# MySQL all possible combinations form multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, combinations

I have three tables, how can I get all posible combinations of ids?

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
FROM t1, t2, t3
WHERE 1
```

This query gives me almost what I want, but also needed to get such rows as:

```
-------------------------
| t1.id | t2.id | t3.id |
-------------------------
|   1   |  NULL | NULL  |
-------------------------
|   1   |   1   | NULL  |
-------------------------
|  NULL |   1   | NULL  |
-------------------------
|  NULL |  NULL |   1   |
-------------------------
 .......................
-------------------------
```

My query gives only without NULL rows

Comment: I have tried the query provided by you and it gives me record with NULL values as you shown. so am bit confuse, do you need records with NULL values OR without NULL values?

Comment: I need rows with NULL values, but it gives me only rows without NULL values

Comment: This query gives rows with NULL value, do you have inserted null in table data as string? can you provide your DB schema

Comment: I need ID fields in which there are no NULL values. But I need them to define all possible sets. In my case I have Region table, Object type table and Deal type table, on front-end user can select category with only one of this params, thats why I need to get all possible variants but with NULL

Comment: If I got it correct then you might needed record with combination like Null, Null, Null (means all 3 have null values) and if it is the case, then per your explanation I think you will have always some value in 1 table as you write front end user select category with 1 of this params. so in that case you wont needed record with Null, Null, Null combination and also this combination wont have any specific value at all

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t1(id int);
create table t2(id int);
create table t3(id int);
insert into t1 values(1);
insert into t2 values(1);
insert into t3 values(1);
select * from 
(select NULL union select id from t1) x1,
(select NULL union select id from t2) x2,
(select NULL union select id from t3) x3
```

Dynamically adding NULLs